# Using PHP to split paragraph into 2 columns

Tags: php, html

We're using the following to split a string into two columns. The string currently splits at a `.`, `?` or `!`.

How do we adjust this to also split at `."`, `?"` or `!"` ?

```
$middle = strrpos(substr($text, 0, floor(strlen($text) / 2)), ' ') + 1;
$adjust = strcspn($text, '.!?', $middle);
```

For example:

This is some text without quotes. "This is text with quotes!" And more text without quotes.

would be split into:

This is some text without quotes. "This is text with quotes!"

and

And more text without quotes.

Comment: If you are splitting on that punctuation then they are not paragraphs but most likely sentences or sentence fragments.

Answer (score 6):

Sounds like a use-case for [`preg_split()`](http://php.net/preg_split):

```
$arr = preg_split('/[.,?!]/', $text, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

[**Demo**](http://3v4l.org/VRhWJ)

Comment: `.` and `?` need to be escaped in `RegEx`. Like `\.` and `\?`.

Comment: @CodeAngry: **No**, they do not, when they're *inside* character classes.

Comment: **It works as you say.** But I would never encourage someone to use them unescaped every-time they want them to act as simple characters. It keeps one paying attention.

Comment: You don't have to escape them, it all depends on the order of their appearance. I think the question asker would also like to handle an optional double quote character succeeding the split character (and btw. "," is not used as a separator ;-) ).

Comment: There is no need to escape these special regex symbols inside character class. Escaping makes it so difficult to read and its not really needed.

Comment: @CodeAngry: I disagree. They're *always* just characters inside character classes (hence the name), so I don't see the need to escape them. ([The only exception is a hyphen (`-`)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20806696/), which denotes a "range of characters").

Comment: @AmalMurali I'm an old dog. I write `C++` mainly. I'm used to writing slightly redundant things just to keep myself paying attention. And I escape gratuitously just to make sure I don't miss any. :)

Comment: Does this really also account for our optional quote marks (.", ?" and !")?

Comment: @RichardTinkler: I don't understand what you mean by "*optional quote marks*". Could you explain?

Comment: We also have to split when a sentence ends with any of these 2-characters: ." or ?" or !"

Comment: @RichardTinkler: It seems I misread your question. Anyway, are you looking for something like [**this**](https://eval.in/105600)?

Comment: @Amal Murali: That's pretty much it with two exceptions: no splitting at commas and the split sentence has to contain the punctuation. For example:

Okay, that is enough. Yes?" Hmm, yeah. Really?" Umm yes!

becomes

1) Okay, that is enough. 2)Yes?" 3)Hmm, yeah. 4)Really?" 5)Umm yes!

Answer (score 1):

If you have to take care of an optional quote character behind your split character, try this:

```
preg_split('/[?!.]"?/', $text, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```